# Show previous position of the item Collection View

Tags: c#, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a collection view that contains 100 items.

When I tap on each item, I enter the page related to that item.

But when I hit the back button and re-enter the list page or collection view, the  shows the first item of list And the list comes again from the beginning!, but I do not want this!

I want When I tap on item 50 and enter the relevant page, when I hit the back button ,   show the   item 50 of my list , not the first item!

What should I do and what code should I enter to get what I want?

I sincerely thank those who help me in this!

this my code selection change:

```
 private async void SelectItemCollectionView(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
        {
           
                
              var item = e.CurrentSelection.FirstOrDefault() as Table;
              if (item==null)
              return; 
              await Navigation.PushAsync(new TablePage(item));
              ((CollectionView) sender).SelectedItem = null;

        }
```

Comment: this should be the default behavior unless you are doing something to cause it to behave differently.  Since you have not posted any code it's impossible to know what the cause may be

Comment: I put the code. @Jason

Comment: are you doing anything in `OnAppearing`?  Have you tried commenting out `              ((CollectionView) sender).SelectedItem = null;`?

Comment: I read the list from API in OnAppearing!@Jason

Comment: when you navigate back OnAppearing is likely firing again and re-initializing your list

Comment: Can you guide me with a code example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use a `bool` flag to ensure you only initialize your page once

```
bool init = false;

void OnAppearing() 
{
  if (!init) {
    init = true;
    
    // do any init tasks here
  }
}
```